# Audio and Video lag/not working after suspend

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, sound, video, suspend

After resuming from suspend, my machine boots fine, but essentially all video and audio malfunctions. 
Audio does not work at all. Video stutters at a constant pattern. That is both in Chrome/Firefox and from local video.

If I try to playback music/video locally, using the default players, there will be no sound and it playback as if it is fastfowarded.

Machine Specs:

Intel i5 2500k
nVidia GTX 465 (Driver version 331.38)
Asus Xonar Audio DG
Gigabyte P67A-UD4-B3

Only fix I've tried is to kill pulseaudio, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can test  these   commands :

1. **Alsa suspend/resume again**

   `sudo alsa suspend`
   `sudo alsa resume`
2. **More alsa restart**

`sudo alsa  force-reload`

3. **Pulseaudio**

`sudo killall -9 pulseaudio`
This will stop and restart    pulseaudio.
Verify soundcard selection and volume setting in sound parameter

4. **Verify alsamixer setting after suspend**:
   Run  alsamixer in a maximized terminal,  use <kbd>F6</kbd> to select soundcard (HDMI or internal soundcard): do you see your soundcard faders ? If yes , tweak all  volumes using left/right arrows to scroll thru faders,  up/down to set each fader levels (set all to max for test) , m key to mute/unmute (unmute all)

Comment: The first command smoothed out flash playback online, but audio still does not work. The second command reverts that improvement and video playback on chrome begins stuttering again.

Comment: there was a typo in alsa force-reload. Also added alsamixer volume setting.

Comment: None of those commands are doing anything for audio. Flash video playback might get better but nothing else does. Seems my soundcard doesn't show up in alsamixer after using alsa force-reload either.